# How can I create a manager script to control all drawn circles at once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The first script is for drawing the circle:
When I attach this script to a gameobject it's drawing a circle around the object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class DrawCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public int segments = 50;
    [Range(1, 50)]
    public float xradius = 5;
    [Range(1, 50)]
    public float yradius = 5;
    [Range(-10, 10)]
    public float height = 0;
    public bool changeBothRadius = false;
    [Range(0.1f, 2)]
    public float lineThickness = 0.1f;
    public bool minimumRadius = false;

    private LineRenderer line;

    void Start()
    {
        line = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        line.startWidth = lineThickness;
        line.endWidth = lineThickness;

        CreatePoints();
    }

    void CreatePoints()
    {
        float x;
        float z;

        float angle = 20;

        for (int i = 0; i < (segments + 1); i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xradius;
            z = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yradius;

            line.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, height, z));

            angle += (360f / segments + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I created a manager script that should control all the circles at once:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CirclesManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objectsToAddCircles;
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public int segments = 50;
    [Range(1, 50)]
    public float xradius = 5;
    [Range(1, 50)]
    public float yradius = 5;
    [Range(-10, 10)]
    public float height = 0;
    public bool changeBothRadius = false;
    [Range(0.1f, 2)]
    public float lineThickness = 0.1f;
    public bool minimumRadius = false;

    void Start()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToAddCircles.Length; i++)
        {
            objectsToAddCircles[i].AddComponent<DrawCircle>();
            objectsToAddCircles[i].AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToAddCircles.Length; i++)
        {
            var lr = objectsToAddCircles[i].GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
            lr.startWidth = lineThickness;
            lr.endWidth = lineThickness;

            var dc = objectsToAddCircles[i].GetComponent<DrawCircle>();
            dc.segments = segments;
            dc.xradius = xradius;
            dc.yradius = yradius;
            dc.height = height;
            dc.changeBothRadius = changeBothRadius;
            dc.minimumRadius = minimumRadius;
        }
    }
}
```

So now each object have the LineRenderer component and the DrawCircle script and now the CirclesManager script is working on all objects fine but if I try to change individual object settings it will not change. For example I can change the xrdaius or yradius sliders in the manager script but if I try to change them in a specific object the sliders won't move will not change.

Can't figure out why the manager script is working but not each individual object with the script and LineRenderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CirclesManager class in Update you have these lines:

```
dc.xradius = xradius;
dc.yradius = yradius;
```

No matter where and how you change individual `DrawCircle` instance radius, these lines would always overwrite those values.

I don`t know what kind of behaviour you want to archive but you can create a bool array so you can manually set which circles would be driven by CirclesManager and which circles would use their own values:

```
// you can change it in the inspector which is handy
// if i'th value of this array is false
// then i'th CircleDrawer GameObject in objectsToAddCircles array
// won't be affected by this manager
public bool changableCircle[];

void Start() {
    // your code
    changableCircle = new bool[objectsToAddCircles.Length];
}

void Update() {
    for(...) {
        // values which are always overwritten by manager
        if(changableCircle[i]) {
            // values which you don't want to be changed by this manager
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working. The behaviour I want I think it's logic. To be able to either control all the circles at the same time or to control only some and some individual. Idn't it logic to be able to control all the objects or only some?